# How can i read value at DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < maxrow1; i++)
        {
            if (clmax1 < double.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString()))
            {
                clmax1 = double.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString());
                clmax.Text = clmax1.ToString();
                double alphamax1 = double.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
                alphaclmax.Text = alphamax1.ToString();
            }

        }
```

This code work on windows form application but i want to read all rows and columns values on WPF.

Comment: What are you really asking about? "_I need double.parse command_" but, but... your code there is already using `double.Parse`. I am utterly confused. Your problem description/question does not make a lick of sense to me. You might want to **edit** your question, improving its **clarity** and making it **accurately** describe your problem...

Comment: I write this code on windows form application. Its work but i want to write the same code on WPF. When i try this code on WPF, it does not work. I want to read the values for all rows on WPF.

Comment: "_It does not work_" is a very poor problem description. It is kinda some sort of problem description, but it is actually not useful/helpful as It does not contain any meaningful information about your problem. You might want to read "[ask]"

Comment: Ah, so the code in your question is not WPF code, but it is rather WinForms code?

Comment: In summary, i want to read values of data from the datagrid on WPF. How can i read? I want to read all rows not only selected rows.

Comment: Yes i read in windows form application with this code. I want to read on WPF. Because i like WPF more than windows form application.

Comment: In WPF, you would normally not read data from the datagrid itself. The datagrid in WPF would just _present_ a collection of data (the collection being provided to the datagrid by your code or by some database connection), and when processing data, you would do the processing on that collection itself, not based on the DataGrid (the DataGrid is just user interface for presenting some data collection, it should not be misunderstood as the data collection itself)

Comment: The usual way to work in wpf is mvvm. You would bind an observablecollection to the itemssource of your datagrid. Instead of then reading data back out of ui, you would work with each item in that collection. Which would have a double property containing the value you want.

Comment: So what can i use instead of datagrid.

Comment: I guess you misunderstand. Use DataGrid for displaying/presenting your data collection in the UI of your application. When you want to operate on the data, operate on the data collection itself. The DataGrid should not be involved when you want to process your data collection.

Comment: I use datagrid because i collect the data from excel. So firstly i collect the data from excel, then i want to use this data on code.

Comment: Bind some ObservableCollection to your DataGrid (you might want to spend some time with WPF binding and DataGrid tutorials/guides, if you are still unfamiliar with setting this up correctly). If you don't have data in the beginning, simply bind an empty ObservableCollection to your DataGrid. Basically, whenever you enter rows/records into your DataGrid, the DataGrid will place an object/item into this ObservableCollection. Any processing your code needs to be done will be done on this ObservableCollection...

Comment: Thanks i study about ObservableCollection.

Comment: I solved this problem with data table.
Here is the code:
double aa = Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[0][3]);
            cl.Text = aa.ToString();
Thank you for everything @elgonzo. I am thankful to you.